# Fetch checkbox values from database and display in the form and submit in prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

I want to fetch checkbox values from database and display in the form and when click on submit the new values should update in Prestashop.

I had done `foreach` with the fetched database values but only one value is displaying.

My code is:

```
protected function getConfigForm()
{         
    $sql = 'SELECT id_order_state,name  FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'order_state_lang';
    $results = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql);    
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        return array(
            'form' => array(
                'legend' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Settings'),
                    'icon' => 'icon-cogs',
                ),
                'input' => array(                   
                    array(
                        'type' => 'checkbox',
                        'label' => $this->l('Select Required Status'),
                        'required' => true,
                        'values' => array(
                            'query' => array(
                                array(
                                    'id' => 'AllFields',
                                    'name' => $this->l('All Fields'),
                                    'val' => 'All',
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'id' => 'OrderID',
                                    'name' => $this->l($row['name']),
                                    'val' => $row['id_order_state'],
                                    'required' => true,
                                ),
                            ),
                            'id' => 'id',
                            'name' => 'name'
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                //     array(
                //         'type' => 'text',
                //         'name' => 'EXPORTORDERS_LOCATION',
                //         'label' => $this->l('Export Location'),
                //     ),
                'submit' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Save'),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Does you query return more than one row..?  If so, you are `return`ing during the first iteration of your loop.  If not, why do you need the loop?

Comment: because in my database there are many status stored, I want to show all the status in the config page as checkbox so i used foreach to display all in that page but only one is displaying

Comment: What I'm saying is that you are only processing the first row of your results because you are doing `return` inside of the `foreach` loop.

Comment: so what should i do? im new to prestashop

Comment: i want to show all values. Can you please help me?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with prestashop. I do not know the proper format for the `input` array.  But, I think that is your problem.

Comment: ok i will wait for someone else to clarify it. Thank you #BizzyBob for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning from the method inside the `foreach` loop. You are then returning with a single value. You should first build a values array inside the `foreach` loop and then build your form:

```
protected function getConfigForm()
{         
    $sql = 'SELECT id_order_state,name  FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'order_state_lang';
    $results = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql);

    $values_query = array(array(
        'id' => 'AllFields',
        'name' => $this->l('All Fields'),
        'val' => 'All',
    ));
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        $values_query[] = array(
            'id' => 'OrderID',
            'name' => $this->l($row['name']),
            'val' => $row['id_order_state'],
            'required' => true,
        );
    }

    return array(
        'form' => array(
            'legend' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Settings'),
                'icon' => 'icon-cogs',
            ),
            'input' => array(                   
                array(
                    'type' => 'checkbox',
                    'label' => $this->l('Select Required Status'),
                    'required' => true,
                    'values' => array(
                        'query' => $values_query,
                        'id' => 'id',
                        'name' => 'name'
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'submit' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Save'),
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: you are right all is coming correctly but i want it in three or four layers because the list is too big. the list going vertically downwards too long, is there ay way to make it in 4 layers??

Comment: how to make all checked when clicked on all fields? can you please give a solution for this and above query?

Comment: This is in my opinion a different topic. Could you please create a new Question for this specific front-end requirement? And accept this answer if it resolves your initial problem? [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: #Florian Lematire Yes i had created new question. Can you please have a look on it?  "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42407106/checkbox-styling-and-making-it-checked"